# One line command to delete all but the last N revisions of a file

Tags: linux, unix

What's a Unix/Linux one-liner that will let me delete all but the most recent N revisions of each file?

I've got a bunch of files with revision numbers as part of a legacy asset-management system:

```
bar.r7.js
bar.r8.js
bar.r9.js
bar.r10.js
bar.r11.js
foo.r1.js
foo.r2.js
foo.r3.js
foo.r4.js
...
```

I want to keep the last three of each, so in the above list the command would delete `bar.r7.js`, `bar.r8.js` and `foo.r1.js`.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to learn how to use version control software.

Comment: There's a reason I said "legacy asset-management system." _Legacy_ as in _I can't change it._

Comment: Have someone else change it, then. There's a limit at how much old cruft a company can use. It's for your own sanity!@

Comment: @grawity Thanks. Yes, I've got a new thing in place, but this is for cleaning up constantly-generated revision from the old thing, and I suspected that someone might enjoy the mental exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for name in foo bar; do
    printf '%s\n' "$name".r*.js | sort -V | head -n -3 | xargs -d '\n' rm -v
done
```

Comment: What if the names (foo, bar) are arbitrary?

Comment: @a paid nerd: Assuming the name is everything up to first `.r`: `ls *.r* | cut -d. -f1 | sort -u | while read -r name; do`

Comment: Also, normally I would make sure everything in the pipeline uses null-terminated names, if it weren't for `head` being hardcoded to split by newline.

Comment: What's `sort -V` ?

Comment: @nerd: Shorthand for `sort --version-sort` (which exists in latest version of GNU coreutils)